# tinymce toolbar floating toolbar

Tags: tinymce, draggable, external, toolbar, floating

I have created an external floating toolbar for tinymce with jQuery.

```
tinyMCE.init({

    ...
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "external",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_resizing : false,

    // make toolbar dragable
    handle_event_callback : function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'click') {
            $('.mceExternalToolbar').draggable();
        }
        return true;
    },
    ...
});
```

It works, but every time I click the `textarea`, the toolbar pops back to the top of the `textarea`.

If I click *in* the `textarea`, move the toolbar, then go click back in the `textarea`, the toolbar pops back to the top of the `textarea`.

Any ideas why this might be happening and how to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the code for the toolbar (editor_template.js) positions it every time the editor handles a mouse up event.

I managed to work around it by changing the external toolbar's id:

```
if (e.type == "click")
{
   var oldid = $(".mceExternalToolbar").attr("id");
   $(".mceExternalToolbar").attr("id", oldid+"_new");
   $(".mceExternalToolbar").draggable();
}
```

This probably has some other repercussions, but it seems to work on my limited tests.